# wp-login.php, file doesn't login to Dashboard, but redirects to homepage (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, authentication

I have a problem with my Wordpress site, namely logging in to the admin dashboard seems impossible. Anytime I do that, it takes me to the site's homepage but before this, I can't create a new page. I have tried these solutions but still no change:

1. Cleared cookies
2. Uploaded a new wp-login.php file
3. Disabled plugins and theme
4. Edited the wp_user for admin
5. defined my homepage url in my wp-config file

> **Note:**  There is no .htaccess file in my wp root directory Anything to help please, my client's really impatient

Comment: Need more info to diagnose.. what host / type of server? If it's running on Apache it needs a proper .htaccess file. What's wp-config.php look like (X out the logins / pws)?

Comment: @JDev518 It is a shared hosting and runs on Apache, I also noticed that forget my pass does the same, like d whole backend is unresponsive

**Below is the wp-config content**
`<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'x');
define('DB_USER', 'x');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'x');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
$table_prefix  = 'wpf0_';
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_HOME','http://happen.com.ng');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://happen.com.ng');
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

**Note**: Some part's been scraped off

Comment: I cant seem to find my .htaccess anywhere

Comment: @JDev518 The server is a Linux/Cpanel type

Comment: @JDev518 Maybe this could help too, I recently installed a plugin(SwiftSecurity- which is now gone), at first the site was showing blank on loading, then I removed it and the site came back. But weeks after, I noticed the login problem, retrieving pass problem, publishing pages

Comment: @JDev518 Thanks for your concern. The issue is been resolved, I undid the hidden setting for files beginning with dot and deleted the .htaccess. The SwiftSecurity plugin left its debris in it

Comment: Ok I'll take another look at it as soon as I get a chance today and let you know.

Comment: And I totally missed that you said it's been resolved. Ok good : ) Any security themed plugins have the ability to wreak havoc on your site if they are not clear about exactly how they are trying to secure it (which files)

Answer (score 0):

After going through other options all I had to do was:

> Look for my .htaccess file(if hidden, make it visible) and delete it.
>   Then after getting through to your admin area update your permalink